# how to read wpa_supplicant.conf file

Tags: android

Can anyone help me to read `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` file in android device through android app programmatically.

I tried the below code to read information stored in `wpa_supplicant.conf` file and display information in a textview.but it returns nothing.

```
try 
{

    Process psProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c"});//root
    File path=Environment.getDataDirectory();
    File myFile = new File("/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf");
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(fIn));
    String aDataRow = "";
    String aBuffer = "";
    while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
        aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
    }
    tv.setText(aBuffer);
    myReader.close();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Done reading SD 'TextAreaAppender.java'",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    tv.setText(e.getMessage());
}
```

Textview displays nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have remount the partition. Otherwise, you have no permission to read / write here.

You can try following before further operation on that folder.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("system/bin/mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs /data");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("system/bin/chmod 777 /data/misc/wifi");
```

Comment: @Junyong i wrote an app that grants superuser access.i'v tried this code, but i got permission denied :/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied). is there any solution?