# new File().exists() return false for existing file

Tags: android, rooted-device

I'm trying to read /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf in my rooted device
this file is available and i can copy it to sdcard without any problem but new File().exists() return false

```
new File("/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf").exists() -> FALSE
```

below code works fine

```
new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"su", "-c", "cp /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/wpa_supplicant.conf"}).start().waitFor();
```

Comment: make sure you have right to read in the process running this code. try File#canRead for example.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work due to the File System Security. You have no right to read or write in this directory unless you remount the partition. Check this question: [how to read wpa_supplicant.conf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595740/how-to-read-wpa-supplicant-conf-file)

One solution is not to use file.exist() but to execute the command "ls"  in the directory of WPA_supplicant and check if the result of the process contains WPA_supplicant.

Comment: It's important to me to find out why this is happened, why .exist() doesn't work

Comment: It does not work due to the File System Security. You have no right to read or write in this directory unless you remount the partition. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595740/how-to-read-wpa-supplicant-conf-file

Comment: The suggested solution that I proposed is an easy solution to build that would work perfectly in your case.

Comment: accept the answer if it has provided you with some help

Answer (score -2):

Try to initialize it first and check its condition using `if` statement:

```
File file = new File("my_path");
if (file.exist()){
    // do something
}
```

And make sure that the path of the file is correct.